# how to check if ADOConnection is open in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

i want to check if ADOConnection is open in the code, then it should close by using an if-else statement like

```
if ADOConnection.open then 
begin
 ADOConnection.Close;
end;
```

Comment: Any help on the above

Comment: I am getting the error when using above code

Comment: I've deleted my answer from here since you've stopped to cooperate. You should tell the details I've asked you for or prove your claim somehow. If you made a mistake, it would be fair to say so. For the others, I've suggested the use of the [`State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property of the ADO connection object, which is the only available state property of this object, but OP claims to get access violation with no further information (at least OS and ADO version). Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi TLama, i am checking the ADO version as you suggested and let u know if i get any version

Comment: I am using inno compiler(Unicode) version

Comment: Hi TLama, The current version of ADOconnection is 6.1 . Please help me on this issue

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I'm having Windows 7 64-bit, ADO 6.1 and the `State` property works fine for me (the same I've tried on Windows XP, no problem there as well). What's more, it shouldn't raise an access violation even when this property wouldn't exist, so it's impossible to say what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Hi TLama, That is working fine when i am checking the connection string in InitializeWizard() procedure but not working when the same code is placed in NextButtonclick() procedure. There i am getting error for the part  (if State= adStateOpen then)

Comment: I would have to see the whole script to advice. There is no difference if you instantiate the connection object in `InitializeWizard` and use it in the `NextButtonClick` event method. An access violation is not an error that I would expect when using variant objects. Sorry, but I have no further time to play "guess what I have wrong in my code" game. Here's [`another pastebin`](http://pastebin.com/MC2PPmcB) that should convince you that the problem is not related to ADO. I'd say The problem is something else in your script. Why don't you want to narrow your problem in a plain new script ?

Comment: Hi TLama,i am able to get the output as expected in the NextButtonClick procedure.Thank u a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome! But for the next time please test carefully before you claim that something doesn't work. I've provided sufficient pieces of code that you could try to convince yourself. It's important to narrow the problem if there's any. Not just work with the whole solution.